# How does @ComponentScan work in Spring 3.2?

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, autowired

I thought `@ComponentScan` was capable of handling multiple packages this way:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foo.bar.service", "com.foo.bar.repository" })
```

but whenever I add more than one package into the array of packages, I get an exception as well as when I use *only* `com.foo.bar` (I thought when using `com.foo.bar`, `com.foo.bar` as well as ALL sub-packages would be scanned.)

How can I tell Spring to scan all the mentioned packages or a package and its sub-packages?

The exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'loginLogoutController': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private com.foo.bar.service.MyService com.foo.bar.controller.LoginLogoutController.myService; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'repositoryMyService': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private com.foo.bar.repository.MyRepository com.foo.bar.service.RepositoryMyService.myRepository; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [com.foo.bar.repository.MyRepository] found for dependency: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: 
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

The repository class is just an interface extending `JpaRepository`.
`MyService` is an interface as usual and `RepositoryMyService` implements `MyService` and is annotated with `@Service`. The `LoginLogoutController` is annotated with `@Controller`.

Comment: You should be able to do what you are saying (just specify the parent package). Can you show more of the class that contains the `@ComponentScan` annotation?

Comment: Have you enabled JPA repository configuration?

Comment: That's what I did in the meantime to make it work: @EnableJpaRepositories